# Dangling reference during asynchronous operation

Tags: c#, asynchronous, reference, xna

Currently I am working on an XNA project and pimped up the `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.SoundEffectInstance`-class a little by creating a wrapper which provides events to signal the different states of the sound (i.e. stopped, playing, paused).

Now I have the following situation: I create an instance of my class "EventSoundEffect" as a local reference, e.g.:

```
public void func(){
...
EventSoundEffect ese = new EventSoundEffect( /*some sound */);
...
ese.Stopped += Callback;    
ese.playAsync();
//method ends directly after ese.playAsync()
}

private void Callback(object sender, EventArgs e){
// do stuff
}
```

I realized the event-firing using the `ThreadPool` and a `while`-loop. Not very nice, but it works.
When the state of the sound changes, I find that in the `while`-loop like

```
//Pseudocode
public void playAsync(){

    sound.Play(); // starts playing sound asynchronously, returns immediately (SoundEffectInstance)

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( obj => {
        while(...){
           if(sound.SoundState == SoundState.Stop)
           break;
        }
        if(SoundStoppedEvent != null)
            SoundStoppedEvent(this, new EventArgs());
        }
   }
}
```

Now, could it actually happen that the GC will strike in between the end of `func()` and `Callback` and so actually collect the object on the heap?
The local reference to the object is lost after `playAsync()`, but the thread from the `ThreadPool` still works on it and eventually a reference will show up at `Callback` (sender).
Could this lead to unforeseen consequences?
Thank you

Comment: Your question is a bit difficult to follow.  How is `playAsync()` implemented?  If you're accessing the object from a thread pool thread then clearly there's a reference to it still alive somewhere.

Comment: @ColeCampbell Thank you for your response. I updated my code to make it a little more obvious - my `playAsync` returns immediately, but the lambda in the `ThreadPool` is still running, after the reference goes out of scope. Depending how long the soundfile plays (may be several seconds), I am not sure if there is a reference remaining so the object couldn't be collected by GC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, could it actually happen that the GC will strike in between the end of func() and Callback and so actually collect the object on the heap?

No, a reference will be held inside the ThreadPool, since you use it ("this") inside your lambda-function.

Comment: Thank you, sounds promising. Do you happen to have any further references about this?

Comment: To elaborate on this answer:  the variables `this` and `sound` in your `playAsync()` method are being _closed over_ by the lambda, which causes it to be _lifted_ into a compiler-generated class which keeps it alive for the duration of the lambda.